# Getting error when trying to pass the dynamic variable in LookUp activity in Azure data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

My requirement is to get the number of error records from the error table generated during pipeline run.
For this I have created a SP which is taking pipeline Id as an Input Parameter and generating count as an output parameter.
I tried to call this Procedure from Lookup activity in ADF using PipelineId as dynamic variable.
But it is throwing an error:

```
 declare @Error_Count int
execute [dbo].[uspErrorRecordCount] '@variables('pipelineId')', @Error_Count output
select @Error_Count as Error_Count
```

Even I tried with both with and without quotes.

Error Message:

> Failure happened on 'Source' side. ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed with the following error: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@variables".',Source=,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Must declare the scalar variable "@variables".,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=137,Class=15,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=2,Errors=[{Class=15,Number=137,State=2,Message=Must declare the scalar variable "@variables".,},],'

Comment: If the answer was helpful , You can [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to enclose the variable inside @{...} so that its value is resulted inplace.

**Example:**

```
declare @Error_Count int
execute [dbo].[uspErrorRecordCount] @{variables('pipelineId')}, @Error_Count output
select @Error_Count as Error_Count
```

**Example:**

Import stored procedure parameters and provide the values there.

[image]

Comment: We can't use the output variable in stored procedure activity. Hence I have used the lookup activity. I tried your approach as well by adding {..} but it didn't work.